# Databind Kendo MobileListView

Tags: data-binding, kendo-ui, datasource

I have a desktop page that works fine. This page uses the Kendo ListView HTML Helper to bind the data and then a C# method in the controller to post to. I'd like to use the same controller method but I can't figure out how to bind the data correctly. Is there a way to do this or am I stuck writing a different method for the mobile view?

Kendo ListView constructor:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ListView(Model.ReservationData)
            .ClientTemplateId("reservationsTemplate")
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("ResInvitationDelete", "ClubProfile").Data("SerializeData"))
                .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id("ReservationID");
                        model.Field<DateTime>("PendingInvitation.RespondByDate");
                        model.Field<DateTime>("ReservationDate");
                    }
                )
                .Update(update => update.Action("ResInvitationUpdate", "ClubProfile").Data("SerializeData")))
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "border-width:0px" })
            .Name("reservationsList")
            .Selectable()
            .TagName("div")
        )
```

C# Controller method in controller:

```
public ActionResult ResInvitationUpdate([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, Reservation reservation)
```